# what is Responder chain in iPhone SDK ?? How it works?

Tags: iphone

what is Responder chain in iPhone SDK ?? How it works ?

Comment: This is your 5th Question in 2 hours and none of them is quite specific. You might want to consult the official documentation more closely before you start asking questions.

Comment: It's also a duplicate. Sigh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768602/what-actually-is-file-owner-and-first-responder-in-iphone-sdk-xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html):

> If the first responder *[to an event or action message]* cannot handle an event or action message, it forwards it to the “next responder” in a linked series called the *responder chain*. The responder chain allows responder objects to transfer responsibility for handling an event or action message to other objects in the application.
>   If an object in the responder chain cannot handle the event or action, it resends the message to the next responder in the chain. The message travels up the chain, toward higher-level objects, until it is handled. If it isn't handled, the application discards it.